# Why does print_r reset a mysqli object?

Tags: php, mysqli

Why is the return value changed?

```
function query($sql){
    $connection=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','123456');
    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    print_r($connection);
    return $connection;
}

print_r(query('gfsfasdfadfafdadsfs'));
```

[Log Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzlrI.png)

Comment: Return value didn't really change, you still got a myslqi object. You just got the last error from your garbage query added to its properties that will be retrieved later.  Just change `print_r(query('gfsfasdfadfafdadsfs'));` to something valid like `print_r(query('SELECT 1'));`

Comment: Why is there no error message in the returned object, look at the image in the question?

Comment: There is, but you must check for it with `mysqli_errno()` and `mysqli_error()` or the properties directly.

Comment: I tried, mysqli_error(query('gfsfasdfadfafdadsfs')); I can't get the error message outside the function, I can get the error message of ''You have an error in your SQL ...' in the function.

Comment: @alex the return value *did* actually change

Comment: Why you re asking? If it's just a curiosity, then you've got the answer - just don't use print_r. If it has some practical implications, you don't have to mingle with mysqli object, mysqli_error or any other stuff. Just [configure mysqli to throw exceptions](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting), that's all

Comment: It is really useful to me, not because of curiosity！

Comment: The thing is that it makes no sense to have such function in place at all. This is a bug which will be fixed in PHP 7.4, but it should not really affect you in real life unless you are doing some manual debugging. There are better ways to debug your connection/query.